# Prove that there exists a canonical isomorphism of A-algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

This question is from an assignment in algebraic geometry and I am struck on it.

> Question: Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $T =\{ t_i \mid i \in I\}$ be a family of elements in $A$ and let $S=\langle T,\cdot\rangle\subseteq A$ be the multiplicative submonoid of $(A,\cdot)$ generated by $T$, i.e. $S$ consists of all finite products of elements in $T$. Then there exists a canonical isomorphism of $A$-algebras $S^{-1} A \to A[X_i\mid i\in I]/\langle t_iX_i -1\mid i\in I\rangle$.

Unfortunately, I don't have much to show in work for this question. Can you please tell how exactly should I define the map?  I can see that $\langle t_i X_i -1 \mid i \in I\rangle $ should be in the kernel of the map. But, except this I don't have any clues?

Kindly consider helping.

Comment: $t_iX_i-1=0$ indicates that $X_i=t_i^{-1}$. So it tells you that $t_i^{-1}\in S^{-1}$ should be mapped to $X_i$.

Comment: It depends on the definition you choose for $S^{-1}A$. There is one using equivalence relation and one using universal property. The second case is trivial (that is why they said the isomorphism is "canonical") and the first one is performed like in Javi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to write an answer I'll rewrite my comment here.

The fact that we are quotienting out by $\langle t_iX_i-1\mid i\in I\rangle$ implies that in the quotient we have $t_iX_i-1=0$ for all $i$, which is equivalent to $t_iX_i=1$. In other words, $X_i$ is the multiplicative inverse of $t_i$. This forces $t_i^{-1}\in S^{-1}$ to be mapped to $X_i$. And this is enough to define a map $S^{-1}A\to A[X_i\mid i\in I]$ if we leave $A$ fixed, i.e., $a\mapsto a$ for all $a\in A$. I'll let you finish the definition of the map from here.

With that definition it is more or less clear that the map is surjective and the kernel is precisely $\langle t_iX_i-1\mid i\in I\rangle$ since the only relation we are introducing is $t_iX_i=1$ from the fact that $t_it_i^{-1}=1$.